# SignalR 2.1.0 preview 2 final update to 2.1.0 rc1 final throws FileNotFoundException when doing services.AddSignalR()

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017, asp.net-core-signalr

Today I tried updating all ASP.NET Core packages in my application from the preview 2 version to the rc1 version.

In my startup.cs file when trying to add services.AddSignalR(); I get the following error

```
Could not load file or assembly 'System.Memory, Version=4.1.0.0...
```

I am currently using VS2017 15.7. Did anyone encounter this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please check your .csproj for:

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />
```

And update any other package in version `Version="2.1.0-preview2-final"` to `Version="2.2.1"`

Remember to download and install `.NET Core SDK 2.1.300-rc1` https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2018/05/07/announcing-net-core-2-1-rc-1/

Comment: Updating my .NET Core SDK fixed the problem, I was still using the preview version, thanks!